# Index(Match()) in VBA Excel with Formulas in Cells

Tags: vba, excel

First time here. Pretty new to coding in general. Just doing this for fun/trying to learn. Appreciate the help in advance.

I'm trying to have my code look at a CSV cell and pull out the values into an array. Then, using that array, Index(Match()) to get dates in the last column into a new array. Then I will look at the latest date and write that into the cell next to CSV cell.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim DepArray As Variant, FinArray As Variant, x As Integer, i As Integer, y As Variant, StartDate As Date
    DepArray = Split(Target, ",")
    x = UBound(DepArray)
    'INDEX(MATCH()) to write to new array of finish dates for prior tasks
    For i = 0 To x
        y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("SH1").Range("A1:E4").Value, Application.Match(DepArray(i), Sheets("SH1").Range("A1:A4").Value, 0), 5)
        FinArray(i) = y
    Next i
    StartDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(FinArray)
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = StartDate
```

I am getting a type mismatch error on the y=Index(Match()) line. I've tried every variable type, I think, declaring y alternatively as an integer and a date. Any thoughts?

FYI I'm using the .Value callouts because in both column A and E, the item numbers and dates are being brought in by functions in the cells.

Also, if you have tips for cleaning up the code or see other things wrong I haven't gotten to yet, I'd love to learn better practices.

Thanks!

Updated code to help with checking. I think I'm getting the Match() right because now the error shows on line MsgBox y(i). I've also tried it as MsgBox y

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B4")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim DepArray As Variant, FinArray As Variant, x As Integer, i As Integer, y As Variant, StartDate As Date
    DepArray = Split(Target, ",")
    MsgBox DepArray(0)
    x = UBound(DepArray)
    MsgBox x
    MsgBox DepArray(x)
    'INDEX(MATCH()) to write to new array of finish dates for prior tasks
    For i = 0 To x
        MsgBox DepArray(i)
        y = Application.Match(DepArray(i), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value, 0)
        MsgBox y(i)
        'FinArray(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E4").Value, Application.Match(DepArray(i), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value, 0), 5)

    Next i
    StartDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(FinArray)
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = StartDate
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Are there worksheet errors (e.g. #N/a, #DIV/0!, etc) in those columns? (F5, Special, Errors)

Comment: Maybe try `Sheets("SH1").Range("A1:E4")` without the `.Value`  Seems like this might be more easily implemented as a Vlookup though?  You also need to dimension `FinArray()`  before you can populate it.

Comment: Thanks for looking! I don't have any errors on the sheet. The code didn't get far enough to modify any cell values. 

I think FinArray is Dimensioned the same as DepArray? See Dim line.

I prefer to use Index(Match()) generally, on my spreadsheets. And even if it could be done easier with Vlookup in this case, I'd like to learn how to properly execute Index(Match()) in VBA.

Thanks Again

Comment: *I think I'm getting the Match() right because now the error shows on line MsgBox y(i)* that's because `y` is not an array. The `Match` function returns a variant, but only a single value. `MsgBox y` *should* work, unless the `Match` returned an error value. You could examine this with a breakpoint on that line and looking at `y` in the Locals window of the VBE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line creates `DepArray` as an array of string:

```
DepArray = Split(Target, ",")
```

Because `Split` returns a string array.

Later, when you do:

```
y = Application.Match(DepArray(i), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value, 0)
```

The `Match` function returns the 1004 error because there is no value of `"1"` in that range, instead there's a value of `1`!

You could probably resolve by casting to long/integer:

```
Dim valueToMatch as Long
valueToMatch = CLng(DepArray(i))
y = Application.Match(valueToMatch, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value, 0)
```

It's also usually a good idea to trap errors, like:

```
If IsError(y) Then
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & CStr(valueToMatch)
    ' Exit sub, or go to next iteration, etc.
End If
```

You also need to `ReDim` the `FinArray`, after this line:

```
x = UBound(DepArray)
ReDim FinArray(x)
```

And uncomment the line that assigns values into this array, otherwise it remains an `Empty` variant, and `Max(Empty)` will return `0` every time :D

Also, you need to do `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of your procedure and then `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of the procedure, in order to avoid possible infinite loop, since  `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = StartDate` will trigger the `Change` event :)

Comment: Thanks, David. I think we're close! I actually chose to use CDbl because the Index() function looks for type Double for argument 2. 

I'm getting the correct value in the box when FinArray(i) shows:
`FinArray(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E4").Value, y, 5)
MsgBox FinArray(i)`

But then, no matter what I change the values to or how I set the cell formatting I get 12:00:00 AM in the cell when it outputs:

`StartDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(FinArray)
Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = StartDate`

StartDate is dimensioned as a Date

Comment: @Gabba48 put a breakpoint on that line, then use the Locals window to examine the actual value of `StartDate`? What does it show?

Comment: Okay wait. I think I can get this. Max(FinArray) is taking the max position, not the max value. So it's taking the last spot in the array which is initialized to 0 or something.

Comment: It looks like you don't dimension `FinArray` properly, let me look again...

Comment: Yes, taht's it. `FinArray` is declared as Variant, it's never assigned any value(s). it's not an array, it's an empty variant so its value will be `0`.

Comment: You'll need to `ReDim FinArray(UBound(DepArray))` and then make sure you uncomment the line that's assigning to `FinArray(i)`.

Comment: Yeah I'd already done some of that. I did `Dim FinArray(9) As Variant` and removed the commenting. The dynamic nature of assigning it to DepArray is great!

One last question: do I need to reset all variable to nothing? Or are they not stored once it exits? As the columns get updated I don't want to leave leftovers.

Comment: VBA is "garbage collected" which means that your object variables are trashed once the procedure exits (excepting any `Static` variables, which you don't have any of).

Comment: I've learned more in the last 30 min than in 6 hours of googling and trial and error. Thanks a million

Comment: @Gabba48 here's one more for ya, a good overview of debugging techniques for VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx